# Windows (partially) claims I have a private key for a foreign certificate

Tags: windows, microsoft-word, vba, certificate

We have a MS  Word document template with vba code produced and signed by an external firm. 
When I view the details of the signing certificate from within Word vba developer tools, it shows up with the hint "You have a private key that corresponds to this certificate" - which sounds weird, given that this is by an external firm.

When I use certmgr.msc to check the same certificate (it *is* the same according to fingerprint and all), it is shown without the private key hint - which is more like what I would haveexpected, but it's stange that the answer differes.

What is this trying to tell me? (I confirmeed this using different accounts on different machines)

Comment: I don't understand the problem you have a self-signed private cert everything you describe is normal

Comment: @Ramhound The certificate is *not* self-signed, it is signed by Thawte. Why is it normal tha a dialog says that I *do* have the private key for a certificate - when I don't (and another equivalent dialog says that I don't)? If I really had the private key, I cold use it to sign as someone else, which I obviously shouldn't  be able to (and indeed the attempt fails - so this is really raher an annoying display problem, but what's behind it?)

Comment: I would by far trust certmgr more than I would trust the vba developer tools. This does look like a long outstanding bug in a less important part of windows (the part called vba developer tools), wrongly deciding that the certificate is numerically linked to some private key you have in some certificate store.

Comment: @harrymc Well, it looks as if the very same API is responsible for both results (at least it is the very same dialog window ...)

Comment: It can be the same API just not called with the same parameters, or differing library versions (64-bit versions are usually newer). Even if same API/library, a bug is still possible with the call parameters. I don't know which versions you use, but note that Word 2010 is 32-bit, while I don't know which certmgr you use.